# Webpack random module loading at runtime

Tags: javascript, amd, webpack

I have a number of modules I'd like to load/don't load conditionally at runtime. However, I do not know the name of the module at bundling time. My code is something like this:

```
function A(depModule){
    return {
        theActionThatDependsOnThatModule: function(){
            require([depModule], function(dep){
                dep.doSomething();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and then I have a bunch of modules that consume the one above, being something like this:

```
require.ensure('../window');
var obj = A('../window');
obj.theActionThatDependsOnThatModule()
```

But I get the 'require.ensure is undefined' error in browser.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So I kinda found a solution. It's ugly, and maybe someone can tell me how to do it better, but in the meanwhile it works for me:

```
function A(depModule){
    return {
        theActionThatDependsOnThatModule: function(){
            depModule(function(dep){
                dep.doSomething();
            });
        }
    }
}

var obj = A(function(cb){
    require(['./window'], cb);
});
obj.theActionThatDependsOnThatModule()
```